# Can I add arbitrary key to all messages created by Kafka Connect from a csv file?

Tags: csv, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I need to mark all messages created by Kafka Connect (spooldir) from a csv file as coming from one same file. Can I add arbitrary key to these messages? (for example the key being the name of the file)

Also if there are two files in unprocessed directory, Kafka Connect would process them one by one? Not mixing messages from different files in a topic stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `InsertField$Key` transform for this.

https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/insertfield.html

However, this adds static data, and therefore will not have direct access to the file that had been read. In other words, events from differing files will end up having the same key being inserted.

> Not mixing messages from different files in a topic stream

All lines of all files will be read into one sink topic; therefore will be mixed, within and across partitions.